# Why is a simple Cypher query so slow?

Tags: java, eclipse, neo4j, cypher

Using Neo4j 2.3.0 Community Edition with Oracle JDK 8 and Windows 7

I am new to Neo4j and just trying how it works with Java. In the Neo4j Browser I created 3 nodes with the following statement:

```
CREATE (c:Customer {name:'King'})-[:CREATES]->(:Order {status:'created'}),
       (c)-[:CREATES]->(:Order {status:'created'})
```

Executed from the Neo4j Browser, the following query returns in 200 ms:

```
MATCH  (c:Customer)-[:CREATES]->(o:Order)
WHERE  c.name = 'King'
RETURN o.status
```

Executing this in Eclipse takes about 2500 ms, sometimes up to 3000 ms:

```
String query = "MATCH  (c:Customer)-[:CREATES]->(o:Order) "
             + "WHERE  c.name = 'King' "
             + "RETURN o.status";
Result result = db.execute(query);
```

This is incredibly slow! What am I doing wrong?
In addition, I ran the following snippet in Eclipse and it only took about 50 ms:

```
Node king = db.findNode(NodeType.Customer, "name", "King");
Iterable<Relationship> kingRels = king.getRelationships(RelType.CREATES);
for(Relationship rel : kingRels) {
    System.out.println(rel.getEndNode().getProperty("status"));
}
```

So there are actually two things I am suprised of:

1. Running a Cypher query in the Neo4j Browser seems to be way slower than doing a comparable thing with the Neo4j Core Java API in Eclipse.
2. Running a Cypher query "embedded" in Java code is incredibly slow compared to the Neo4j Browser solution as well as compared to the plain Java solution.

I am pretty sure that this cannot be true. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please try with `MATCH  (c:Customer{name:"King"})-[:CREATES]->(o:Order)` and remove the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I had already this before raising the question but there was no change in the performance.

Comment: Do you have indexes on `Customer(name)` and `Order(status)`?

Comment: I do not have any indexes but since there are only 3 nodes and 2 relationships in my database indexing should not have a big impact.

Comment: I now created indexes as you proposed. The Cypher query in the Neo4j Browser really became faster (<50 ms). Unfortunately, the Cypher query I execute from Eclipse still takes more than 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

**How do you measure it?** if you measure the full runtime, then your time includes, jvm startup, database startup and class-loading and loading of store-files from disk.

Remember in the browser all of that is already running, and warmed up etc.

If you really want to measure your query, run it a number of times to warm up and then measure only the query execution and result loading.

Also consider using indexes or constraints as indicated and parameters, e.g. for your customer.name.

Comment: For the Cypher query, I measure the `currentTimeMillies` right before and right after calling `execute`. For the Core API I measure the whole try-block - and it is still a lot faster.
I even ran the two things in one `main` method, starting with the Core API. Therefore I doubt that it is a matter of warming up. Nevertheless, I ran it several times: with no remarkable change.